# A question about irreducible polynomials on a variety

Tags: polynomials, invariant-theory

Let $a,b,c,d$ be rational numbers such that $a^3c+b^3-6abc-abd+9c^2+3cd+d^2=0$ and $c \neq -c -(a^3-6ab+3d)/9$. Such numbers can be find by setting $a = x+y+z, b = xy+xz+yz, c = xyz, d= xy^2+yz^2+zx^2$ hence they are some generating invariants of the cyclic group $C_3$.
Is it true, that one of the polynomials
$p(t) = t^3-at^2+bt-c$ or $p^*(t) = t^3-at^2+bt+c+(a^3-6ab+3d)/9$ is irreducible over the rationals (and hence has Galois group $C_3$)? I have done some computer experiments with SAGE Math, and it seems that the answer is yes, but I can't come up with a proof. I posed the question also [here at math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2116514/a-question-about-irreducible-polynomials-on-a-variety) but got no answer.

Notice that $\tau(a,b,c,d) = (a,b,-c -(a^3-6ab+3d)/9,d)$ is an invoultion of the variety defined above.

If the conjecture above is true, then this could be used to construct a polynomial with Galois group $C_3$, for instance
$p(t,x) = t^3 - 6t^2x + 11tx^2 - 17/3x^3$ would be irreducible for $x \neq 0$ and has discriminant $x^6$ which is a square in the rationals, hence the galois group is $C_3$.

Comment: That polynomial $t^3-6t^2x+11tx^2-17/3x^3$ is homogeneous so it's easily checked to be irreducible for all $x\not=0$ -- if it factored for one $x$ it would factor for all of them. Not only are all the Galois groups $C_3$, all the extensions you get are the same.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your comment. Do you have an idea for the general case?

Comment: Your more conceptual questions about group rings are easier to work on than these explicit special cases which, as you've seen, involve working with unwieldy polynomials. Don't expect anything for free though -- you can try and prove the inverse Galois problem this way but of course this technique has been tried to death already, so we can't really hope to get a cheap criterion which spits out field extensions of the rationals with a given finite group as Galois group using these sorts of methods. Maybe it's true in this case, maybe it's not -- maybe a random dioph eqn has solns, maybe not.

Comment: Ok, I understand your concerns. That makes sense! Thanks for your comment. I have one question: How do you see, that all the extensions one gets of the polynomial in $x$ are the same?

Comment: Just rescale t. It's homogeneous.